# Store Date Format in elasticsearch

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, datetime-format, elasticsearch-mapping

I met a problem when I want to add one datetime string into Elasticsearch.

The document is below:

```
{"LastUpdate" : "2013/07/24 00:00:00"}
```

This document raised an error which is `"NumberFormatException" [For input string: \"20130724 00:00:00\"]`

I know that I can use the Date Format in Elasticsearch, but I don't know how to use even I read the document on the website.

```
{"LastUpdate": {
    "properties": {
        "type": "date", 
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"}
    }
}
```

and

```
{"LastUpdate": {
    "type": "date", 
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
}
```

are wrong.

How can I transfer the datetime string into date format in Elasticsearch?

How can I store the datetime string directly into Elasticsearch?

Comment: one can use double-pipe to support multiple format. e.g. "yyyMMdd||yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are nearly there. Set your mapping like this:

```
{"LastUpdate": {
    "type" : "date",
    "format" : "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"}
}
```

Read the docs on [the date mapping and its options](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) and [the date format parameter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) (one of the options to the date mapping).

Good luck!

Comment: How "format" knows the datetime string is "2013/07/24 00:00:00" ? Or it will use the datetime now ? I change to "LastUpdate": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"}, it raised another error which is "ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [type]]"

Comment: That is the mapping I gave. The `"format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"` tells elasticsearch to accept dates in that format.

Comment: How can I push/let elasticsearch know the what data is ?

Comment: Oh, I should define the data type before I index them, right ?

Comment: Ah, you need to set up a mapping first. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ramseykhalaf/6070512).

Comment: Look at the elasticsearch docs [on put mapping api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/)

Comment: Think of mapping = schema in SQL world. Not really that accurate, but will help you understand what mapping means

Comment: Done, one more question. Is id must be a number, I use sha1 of one string, and it's seems doesn't work. I found that your search is also brilliant.

Comment: What's the different between {key : 1} and {"key" : 1} in elasticsearch ? You didn't use double quote, but still works.

Comment: You should use double quotes, I was being lazy, and some places it works, but it is NOT the standard. `_id` is stored as a string. If you give a number as the `_id` it will be stored as a string representation of that number.

Comment: Any reason why in my document the date appears as long even with the format as custom?

Comment: I believe the date is parsed according to your format. It will then be stored as some kind of `datetime` internally, which is stored as a `Long` (in Java) representing the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! Still having trouble with using the range on dates.

Comment: Dead links in answer. Here's the updated urls.
Core Types: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html
Mapping Date: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/mapping.html#mapping-date

Comment: @ocergynohtna Thanks for the heads up. But actually the links you gave weren't exactly what I was linking to prior. Have updated answer.