# How to sort elasticsearch results by distance?

Tags: foselasticabundle

I'm using elasticabundle for symfony2 and I want to sort results I'm seeking by distance 
I'm new to elasticsearch and I don't know how I can start 
the query I'm using :

```
$c = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.cities_index.cities');
$nameQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$nameQuery->setFieldQuery('tokens', $city);
$nameQuery->setSort(array("distance" => "asc"));// I want to achieve this
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

here is what I did following the example as provided by [Dimitris Tsarouhas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671580/combination-of-two-different-filters-in-one-query-elastica)

The following setup allows to filter by keyword, order by `id`, and add all sort of other filtering using the `$boolQuery ->addMust($yourfilter)` formula.

We fetch the keyword as posted by a form. This is `$data['query']` and by default we use it to perform a `_all` search, thus searching throughout all the fields listed in our `config.yml` file. To perform this search, we use the `QueryString` object, as this allows us to use wildcards.

We then look if exists the variable `$data['status']`, which comes through a dropdown select box (please note the use of strtolower(), without which the query wouldn't work - either that or you set up your own case-insensitive analyzer). If so, we use it to filter our results.

By default, we also want to narrow down our search and pick up only active users.

```
$data = $form->getData();
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.search.user');

$keyword = $data['query'];
$status= $data['status'];

$keywordQuery = new QueryString;
$keywordQuery->setQuery('*' . $keyword . '*');

$query = new Query();
$query->setQuery($keywordQuery);
$query->setSort(array('id' => array('order' => 'asc')));

$boolQuery  = new Bool();

$active= new Term();
$active->setTerm('active', true);
$boolQuery ->addMust($active);

if (!empty($status)) {
    $statusQuery = new Term();
    $statusQuery->setTerm('status', strtolower($status->getName()));
    $boolQuery ->addMust($typeQuery);
}

$query->setFilter($boolQuery);

$entities = $finder->find($query);
```

And of course do not forget to import the necessary libraries:

```
use
    Elastica\Query\QueryString,
    Elastica\Query,
    Elastica\Filter\Bool,
    Elastica\Filter\Term
;
```

Remember that to be able to perform actions on fields (searching, sorting, etc) these haveto be included in your `config.yml`. Of course, this would cause the field to be automatically picked up when searching generally onto a certain entity. So, if you need to avoid this, but you still need certain fields to be available to elastica. just define it as showed below:

```
user:
    mappings:
        name: ~
        surname: ~
        status: ~
        active: { include_in_all: false }
        id: { include_in_all: false }
```